# save button background-color in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying now to switch the colors everytime user clicks on the button, and save background-color in localStorage. I've tried several options, but until now I didn't get it to work. Anyone a solution how to tackle this? thank u

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>LocalStorage Background Colour Changer</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
        getColour = localStorage.background;
        $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', getColour);
    }
    
    $('.btn-secondmenu').click(function() {
        if (getColour == 'blue') {
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'red');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'blue');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
        }
    });
</script>
<button class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "saving the color in local storage"?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you trying to reference it again in the future?

Comment: Try to wrap your script with `$( document ).ready(function() {` 

`});`

Comment: you can use toggleClass instead of local Storage ,are you looking for something like this-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqyVQR

Comment: @NagaSaiA He is looking for persistent storage, therefore switching classes can not replace localStorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS Fiddle has problems with localStorage.
Here is [JS Bin](https://output.jsbin.com/mitakutina).

The problem is, you weren't setting the variable `getColour` properly.
You weren't actually updating it when the button is pressed.

Also, the button wasn't loaded when you were trying to set event listener to it.
Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` when using jQuery.

*JS*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getColour;
  if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
    getColour = localStorage.background;
    $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', getColour);
  }

  $('.btn-secondmenu').on('click', function() {
    if (getColour == 'blue') {
      getColour = 'red';
      $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', 'red');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
    } else {
      getColour = 'blue';
      $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', 'blue');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
    }
  });
});
```

*HTML*:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>
```

---

**Edit**:
As requested, the background will be different for each page.

*JS*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var getColourKey = 'background-' + window.location.search.match(/ID=(\d+)/)[1];
  var getColour;

  if (localStorage.getItem(getColourKey) !== null) {
    getColour = localStorage.getItem(getColourKey);
    $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', getColour);
  }

  $('.btn-secondmenu').on('click', function () {
    if (getColour == 'blue') {
      getColour = 'red';
      $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', 'red');
      localStorage.setItem(getColourKey, 'red');
    } else {
      getColour = 'blue';
      $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', 'blue');
      localStorage.setItem(getColourKey, 'blue');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank u for your answering man it works like a charm. i have just a question. i saw this kin of kines in many javascript codes
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js">` what is it and how we know which one we have to use thank u

Comment: Well, you should generally use the latest one. Once your code depends on syntax of some version of jQuery, you should stick to it if next versions introduce breaking changes.

Comment: The SO snippet doesn't work for some reason. Replaced with bare snippets.

Comment: hey man i just realized something. i use this code in multiple pages in my website and when i click on a button in one page it causes to change other pages button background too how can i fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117517/discussion-between-malekian-and-slayther).

Answer (score 2):

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZSKxkaPzpZxpx61a3Iu?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<button class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null)
    {
        getColour = localStorage.background;
        $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', getColour);
    }
    else
    {
        getColour = 'green';
    }


    $('.btn-secondmenu').click(function() {
        if(getColour == 'blue')
        {
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'red');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
        }
        else
        {
            getColour = 'blue';
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'blue');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi man thank u very much for your answering . i think we make a big step. this code can save button color after reload. but i realized a problem. if you notice and run your code u can just change the button color for once and if u want to do it again and change it back to first color you have to refresh the page at first and then click on it to change it. could u please take a look at this thank u man

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change

```
getColour = localStorage.background;
```

to

```
getColour = localStorage.getItem('background');
```

Comment: hi man thank you for your answering. still it does not work. could u please check whole code yourself thank u

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the event listener before setting the actual button.

Put the scripts after the button or use the `document.ready`

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
}
```

or use the `.on` method.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-secondmenu', function() {
    // Code
})
```

Comment: hi thank u for your answering still it does not work  could u please  check whole code yourself thank u or maby make  a jsfiddle for it. thank u man i am stuck with this code about 3 days

Comment: @Malekian change the declaration of `getColour` as suggested by @Anupam.

Comment: @Slayther He tried that with moving the code below the button?

Comment: Not sure, but that is not the (only) problem. There is something else.

Comment: @Slayther what else? It's a very simple code and it works on a local HTML file a created for this purpose.

Comment: It works for you? What do you mean? Can you change the color by pressing the button?